# How to hide jQmobile page on default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

How do you hide a page included by jquery mobile. I would like to have a mobile version of the site and a desktop version but the mobile version automatically loads up. How do I change this?

code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- For Mobile Devices -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

        <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="../global/global.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div >
        <!-- The View Page (Summary) -->
        <div data-role="page" id="summary">
            <div data-role="header">
            </div>
            <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                <div class="jumbotron container">
                    <center>
                        <img src="removeLogo.jpg" />
                    </center>
                    <h2 class="txt-center"><u>Controls</u></h2>
                    <a class="btn btn-default">View</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="summary">
            <div data-role="header">
            </div>
            <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                <div class="jumbotron container">
                    <center>
                        <img src="removeLogo.jpg" />
                    </center>
                    <h2 class="txt-center"><u>Controls</u></h2>
                    <a class="btn btn-default">View</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </bod
```

y>

Comment: What do you mean it didn't let you post code? Did you get an error?

Comment: ahh.. yes.. this is only for people who are new to the site... You can put the link in between backticks `like this`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DOM is not ready at the time your script runs. Put it in a DOM [ready event handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(function () {
    // Interact with the DOM in here
});

// Or, the slightly longer version
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Interact with the DOM in here
});
```

Alternatively, move your JavaScript to the end of the body (just before the closing `</body>` tag is the common place, but anywhere after the elements you need to refer to will work). By doing that, by the time your script is parsed, the browser has already parsed the preceding markup and has an almost-complete DOM tree ready for you to access.

Comment: 11 times out of 10 this is the problem :P

Answer (score 0):

Ok . I think the reason is, you are trying to reach #left-placeholder but it wasn't loaded yet.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <LINK href="../styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="leftcol">
                <a href="practice.html"><div class ="left-column-item">Practice!</div></a>
                <a href="aboutUs.html"><div class ="left-column-item">About Us!</div></a>
                <a href="contactUs.html"><div class ="left-column-item">Contact Us!</div></a>
            </div>
        <div id="left-placeholder">abc</div>
        <div id ="left-pusher"></div>
        <div id ="content">Math Practice Site <br> hello</div>
    </body>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
        alert($('#left-placeholder').html());
    </script>
</html>
```

Put your script underneath it and it should be fine. Or start your script after page was loaded like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     alert($('#left-placeholder').html());
});
```

Sources: 
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: to avoid this problem I almost always add script in whole file like this : <script src="myscript" type="text/javascript"></script>
and inside $(document).ready();
:)

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){` is unnecessary. `$(function(){` is good enough.